# How to visible/invisible a Text Object in Crystal Report using formulae...

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

i'm having problem in hiding a text object in crystal report using .....
I want to visible a text object name "lblDup" when count(it is a integer field in table "IdMaker_DB") is greater than 1 else lblDup should be invisible....

```
if({IdMaker_DB.Count}>1)then //what should i write here
```

i have tried my best but couldn't got success......
I'm using visual studio 10, crystal report,C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the if-then-else construction here. The suppression formula for the text object should just be `{IdMaker_DB.Count}>1`